# Apache Not Starting on XAMPP due to AccessFileName not allowed here

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

Apache and MySQL worked fine yesterday, new install along with Drupal 8 install.  Everything worked fine yesterday.

Using XAMPP v3.2.1 and after PC restart (Windows Vista) today Apache no longer starts.  Received this error in the control panel:

```
12:45:52 PM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
12:45:52 PM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:45:52 PM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:45:52 PM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:45:52 PM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:45:52 PM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
12:45:52 PM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

After some research went to cmd and ran c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe

Error:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 265 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: AccessFileName not allowed here
```

Opened httpd.conf

```
264 AllowOverride All
265 AccessFileName .htaccess
```

Those lines were within < Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs" >...< /Directory > section

Added a blank .htaccess file to the /htdocs/ folder

There is a .htaccess file in the /xampp/htdocs/drupal/ folder.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

AccessFilename may only be used in the global server configuration or directly inside a virtualhost block. It cannot be used in a Directory context. Put it outside (before) the Directory block, and it will work.

Comment: It was placed there during installation.  I commented it out to keep things rolling and seemed to work.  Should I move it?

Comment: You should move it outside the Directory stanza, yes.